# Why am i not able to login a user?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

here is my initialize method in AppController

```
public function initialize()
    {
        $this->log('called', LOG_DEBUG);
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ],
                    'userModel' => 'Users'
                ]
            ],
            'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
            'storage' => 'Session',
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ]
        ]);
        $this->Auth->allow();
    }
```

here is my login method

```
public function login()
    {
        $this->log($this->request->getBody(), LOG_DEBUG);
        try {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $user = $this->Auth->identify();
                if ($user) {
                    $this->log('valid','debug');
                    $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                }else{
                    $this->log('invalid','debug');
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->log($e, LOG_DEBUG);
        }
    }
```

here is my post request from the log in login method 
{"username":"test@test.com","password":"Test@123"}

Comment: And what is wrong?

Comment: not able to login. always printing invalid. i created a new user also, still no luck.

Comment: And what is your Users model mapping?

Comment: For that you need to use the finder method in the model, to use email column as username and change **username' => 'email',** TO **username' => 'username',** in auth config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ],
```

It says "use `email` field as username and `password` as password". You are posting `username` not `email`

From docs:

> fields - The fields to use to identify a user by. You can use keys
>   username and password to specify your username and password fields
>   respectively.

Could work with `{"email":"test@test.com","password":"Test@123"}` but that depends on your Users model mappling.

Comment: @RajatTanwar You can accept answer to unambiguously indicate that fact. Best of luck!